# EOL while scanning string literal Python any pointers?

Tags: python

i have this code:

```
GDP=input(int("what is the exchange rate for the pound today?"))
USD=input(int("what is the exchange rate for the dolar today?"))
print("thank you")

menu = "What would you like to exchange today?:\n\1.dolar to pound\n\
    \n\2.pound to dolar\n\
    answer == int(input(menu)

if answer == 1:
    amount1 = input(int("how much would you like to convert?"))
    print(amount1/GDP= answer1 +(2% answer1=answer2)
          print(answer2"is the amount of money")

if answer == 2: 
    amount2= input(int("how much would you like to convert?"))
    print(amount2/USD=answer3 +(2% answer3=answer4)
    print (answer4"is how much money")
```

and it says :EOL while scanning string literal can anyone help i have no idea what is wrong

Comment: You forgot the closing quote(s) on the assignment of `menu`.

Comment: Which can be easily noticed by the weird syntax highlighting...

Answer (score 1):

To create a multiline string, use triple quotes (`"""`):

```
multiline_string = """This is a
                   multiline string"""
```

Answer (score 0):

You failed to close the quote on

```
menu =
```

And you failed to close the paren on

```
answer =
```

And you use == on that line where you should use =

Answer (score -1):

correct like this:

```
GDP=input(int("what is the exchange rate for the pound today?"))
USD=input(int("what is the exchange rate for the dolar today?"))
print("thank you")

menu = "What would you like to exchange today?:\n\1.dolar to pound\n\
\n\2.pound to dolar\n\"  ### see here 
answer == int(input(menu)) ### see here

if answer == 1:
amount1 = input(int("how much would you like to convert?"))
print(amount1/GDP= answer1 +(2% answer1=answer2)
      print(answer2"is the amount of money")

if answer == 2: 
amount2= input(int("how much would you like to convert?"))
print(amount2/USD=answer3 +(2% answer3=answer4)
print (answer4"is how much money")
```

Comment: Without any description, you're forcing the reader to go character-by-character to see what you changed. Your answer will be more useful if  you both tell what the answer is, _and_ show the code.